# How to extract the specific content from the xml file with namespace in it, collected from an API? The below details are

Tags: xml, python-3.x, xml-namespaces

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<service xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/app" xmlns:app="http://www.w3.org/2005/app" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xml:base="https://api*.successfactors.com/odata/v2/">
    <workspace>
        <atom:title>Default</atom:title>
        <collection href="User">
            <atom:title>User</atom:title>
        </collection>
        <collection href="FOLegalEntityLocalUSA">
            <atom:title>FOLegalEntityLocalUSA</atom:title>
        </collection>
        <collection href="DGFieldValue">
            <atom:title>DGFieldValue</atom:title>
        </collection>
        <collection href="NameFormatGO">
            <atom:title>NameFormatGO</atom:title>
        </collection>
    </workspace>
</service>
```

I want to extract the value (User,FOLegalEntityLocalUSA,etc..) of .

```
from xml.etree.ElementTree as ET.
...
...
response = requests.get(url, auth=auth_values)
print (response.text)
doc = ET.fromstring(response.content)
namespaces= {'web':'http://www.w3.org/2005/app','atm':'http:   
//www.w3.org/2005/Atom'}
for work in doc.findall('web:workspace',namespaces):
   coll = work.find('web:collection',namespaces)
   for a in coll.findall('atm:title',namespaces):
      print (a.text)
```

Its only printing first single value (atom:title) "User" now. Dont know how to loop it to get all the (atom:title) values.

I have tried all possibility of extracting the title. No luck so far. I'm currently stuck and dont know what to do . Please help me. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your XML example is missing the namespace declaration for the `atom` namespace prefix.

I guess the XML content you display in the question is not complete? (*the question now has updated, correct XML content*)

Assuming there is a `xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"` declaration in there somewhere, the code to get the `atom:title` element should be:

```
for collection in d.findall('collection'):
    r = title.find('{http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}title').text
    # or
    r = title.find('atom:title', namespaces={'atom': 'http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom'})
```

*Update:*

This is how you get all the titles:

```
namespaces= {'app':'http://www.w3.org/2005/app','atom':'http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom'}

for workspace in doc.findall('app:workspace', namespaces):
    for collection in workspace.findall("app:collection", namespaces):
        for title in collection.findall("atom:title", namespaces):
            print(title.text)
```

Comment: Exactly the same. could you please tell me what is "some_element" in your answer and also could you tell me how to extract the whole titles and save it in the list (list.append(title))from the xml? Thanks

Comment: Updated the code example. Could you please post an example of the XML input? I believe there is a namespace declaration missing.

Comment: Hi, I used for collection in work.iter('*') in the second line and it worked very well. Thanks for your help mate.

Comment: Great, please consider upvoting and/or accepting my answer.

Comment: I couldn't able to do it because I'm a new user. I surely will upvote once I reach 15 reputation. Thanks mate.